# How to display boxed numeric characters on web page

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, adobe-illustrator

I'm working on a PDF to HTML project. In the original .ai file, some numeric characters are displayed in a box:

[image]

Although I know the font used in the file is GothicMB101Pro DeBold-83pv-RKSJ-H, I don't have the font file on my machine (and of course the original designer is long gone). In my illustrator, it appear like this:

[image]

The 1) part is *one* single character - not "1" and ")", so at least I know it's not some form of kerning but some unicode character. But I couldn't find any match in my search. The "enclosed numeric" characters ① aren't the same.

Since I'm not sure which character it is, and being not very knowledgeable in Japanese (it seems like a very common occurrence in Japanese language), I couldn't satisfy my client's requirement.

What are those characters and how do I get them onscreen?

Comment: The red box ISN'T part of the design. That's illustrator telling you you're missing the font. What happens if you let it substitute another font (preferably one with multiple character sets) when the dialog appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess, that since the output you are seeing without the original font installed, consists of two characters, the original also consisted of two characters, first of which is a regular one (in that case, number 1), and the second one is a [combining character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character). There is one for a [combining enclosing square](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20de/index.htm), and this is probably the one that is rendered as closing parenthesis ")" that you see in the output. Using the number 1 and the enclosing square (at least in my browser in the stackoverflow answer editior) gives me the required result, as shown below:

1⃞

If your font does not render the enclosing square, it is probably the fault of your font, that is used as a fallback. But without knowing which font exactly is used as a replacement, it is hard to say if it is possible to work around the issue.

Comment: Nice! thanks for the info. Although the font I'm using on the website doesn't support the "combining" feature, Google lead me to a trick using negative letter-spacing to overlap the 2 characters, resulting in a nice "boxed numeric".